# Launch iOS fails on init. Runs locally

Tags: javafx, gluon, hessian

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.caucho/hessian'
    }
    maven {
        url'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
} 

mainClassName = 'com.demoapp.DemoApp'

dependencies {

     compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.1.0'
     compile 'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.2'
     compile 'com.caucho:hessian:4.0.7'
     compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
     compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.9'
}

jfxmobile {
     downConfig {
         version '3.0.0'
         plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
     }

     android {
         manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
     }
     ios {

         infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
         forceLinkClasses = [
            'com.demoapp.**.*', 
            'com.gluonhq.**.*', 
            'io.datafx.**.*', 
            'javax.annotations.**.*', 
            'javax.inject.**.*', 
            'javax.json.**.*', 
            'org.glassfish.json.**.*', 
            'com.caucho.**.*', 
            'com.google.code.gson.**.*', 
            'org.apache.poi.**.*'

        ]
    }
}
```

Error  Exception in Application init method
QuantumRenderer: shutdown
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application init method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:109069952)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:109069952)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:109069952)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.demoapp.DemoApp$$Lambda$1.()V
    at com.demoapp.DemoApp.init(DemoApp.java:109070784)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:109070784)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:109070784)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:109070784)

Any idea where to search for the init-Error when deploying..? Thanks.

Init:

```
@Override
public void init() {

    NavigationDrawer drawer = new NavigationDrawer();

    NavigationDrawer.Header header = new NavigationDrawer.Header("demo inc", "smart teamwork", new Avatar(21, new Image(DemoApp.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png"))));
    drawer.setHeader(header);

    drawer.getItems().addAll(primaryItem, secondaryItem, thirdItem);

    primaryItem.setSelected(true);

    addViewFactory(PRIMARY_VIEW, () -> (View) new PrimaryView().getView());
    addViewFactory(SECONDARY_VIEW, () -> (View) new SecondaryView().getView());
    addViewFactory(THIRD_VIEW, () -> (View) new ThirdView().getView());
    addLayerFactory(MENU_LAYER, () -> new SidePopupView(drawer));

}

@Override
public void postInit(Scene scene) {
    Swatch.ORANGE.assignTo(scene);

    scene.getStylesheets().add(DemoApp.class.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
    ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).getIcons().add(new Image(DemoApp.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));

    switchView(SECONDARY_VIEW);
}
```

Comment: Can you try with `'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.3'`?

Comment: thanks for the hint. but it is still the same error. any other idea than that?

Comment: The jfxmobile plugin since 1.1.0 applies retrolambda to all the dependencies. If any of them has it already applied that will fail. To make sure none of them uses, replace `compile` with `compileNoRetrolambda` in hessian, gson and poi. Charm 4.1.0 and afterburner 1.6.3 don't use retrolambda already.

Comment: i did try that before - but also without luck.. ?? thanks again.

Comment: Clean the project before calling `launchIOSDevice`. It might use some old cache classes.

Comment: Damn! Tidy up is always a good idea. Thank you...!!

Comment: Indeed, will post it as answer so it can be of any help to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception shows that a lambda expression is failing. Probably those in your `init` method with the view suppliers.

Possible reasons for this exception are:

*Retrolambda*

The jfxmobile plugin since version 1.1.0 [applies](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.0.0/#_retrolambda) retrolambda to all the dependencies. But you can't apply it twice.

The first step will be checking which dependencies might use retrolambda.

Charm 4+ doesn't use it. Afterburner 1.6.2 does, so either you change it to:

```
dependencies {
     compileNoRetrolambda 'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.2'
}
```

or you use the brand new version that excludes it:

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.airhacks:afterburner.mfx:1.6.3'
}
```

To make sure none of the other dependencies use it, replace `compile` with `compileNoRetrolambda` in hessian, gson and poi.

*Cache*

Also, when updating projects with lower versions of the jfxmobile plugin, it is possible that you have a previous build on your cache. This might contain classes that you compiled with retrolambda.

While the code is the same, Gradle will skip compiling them again, but when the retrolambda plugin is applied again over them, this will fail.

To avoid this problem, an easy solution is using `clean` before building and deploying your project: Run `./gradlew clean launchIOSDevice`.